# Internal microphone is not working

Tags: skype, microphone

Basically I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and have tried a couple of solutions from this forum but no luck yet, I'm currently using Ubuntu 13.04 and I've tried to use the mic on Skype but it just won't work, it doesn't seem to work from the system settings either.

Comment: If I remember right the mic. is muted by default in Ubuntu?

Comment: Thanks but mine is not muted ):

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Ubuntu 12.04, and tried this solution described 
in a youtube video:

- [How to fix not working microphone in Ubuntu 13.04-10.04](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tULmqpe5Yos)

It boils down to edit the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf using

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add the following line:

```
options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1
```

My mic is now working, but I hear some minor cracks.

Comment: I just noticed a similar answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128841/internal-microphone-jack-not-working-on-hp-pavilion-dv1000-laptop?rq=1

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work either. ):